# Implementing ClassLoader.getResource(String) without a protocol handler

Tags: java, classloader

My class loader resolves resources to a source that does not have a url handler eg it gets resources from a database. This of course poses a problem for ClassLoader.getResource(String) which returns a URL. For the URL.openConnection() etc to work i need a protocol handler, which poses an additionoal problem. How cna i map the URL to my data provider without installing a custom Url protocol handler which requires me to set a system property at startup. The problem with url protocol handlers is they are static and must be set at startup while my class loaders are dynamic and can come from many places.

Is there are way to solve this elegantly without a protocol handler ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you're implementing `ClassLoader.getResource(String)` yourself can you not use the [constructor for `URL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.net.URLStreamHandler%29) that takes in the protocol handler as one of its arguments?

```
public URL(String protocol,
           String host,
           int port,
           String file,
           URLStreamHandler handler)
    throws MalformedURLException
```

Comment: Thanks i didnt spot that - obvious and appears to be perfect :)